# Where to run code for android app upgrade (like a database migration)

Tags: android

I store various session information in `SharedPreferences` and my database models using `GreenDao`. During a major update in Android, I will be most likely replacing both `SharedPreferences` with new key value pairs and `GreenDao` with updated models.

In any case, I would like to run 1 time code that clears both out. Where should I put this code in Android?

Comment: start the service in splash screen may be if the user is authenticated ...depends upon your apps purpose..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [a manifest-registered receiver for `ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED) to kick off a `JobIntentService` to do the work. That broadcast is sent after your app is upgraded. In the `JobIntentService`, you would check to see if the migration work is needed (e.g., examine existing data structures) and, if it is, do that work.

In many cases, that work will be completed long before the user winds up launching your app post-upgrade. For example, if the user has auto-upgrade enabled for this app in the Play Store, your upgrade might occur while the user is sleeping. In that case, your `JobIntentService` has plenty of time to get everything done.

However, it is possible that the user will launch your app prior to that work having been completed, either because that work is in progress or because the `JobIntentService` has not begun yet. For example, the user gets the `Notification` to upgrade the app, manually invokes the upgrade, and then immediately clicks the Run button from the resulting screen. You will need to detect that scenario and deal with it as you see fit.

Comment: Im surprised that Android doesn't have some more robust built-in support for this kind of stuff. This seems awfully haphazard to me.

Comment: @AlanSTACK: Well, usually, we just lazy-migrate. For example, `SQLiteOpenHelper` offers database migrations (and Room layers atop them). `SharedPreferences` rarely needs a migration, and if you do, consider wrapping your `SharedPreferences` access in a repository, so that you can lazy-migrate that stuff as well.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `lazy-migrate`?

Comment: @AlanSTACK: You seem to want to proactively migrate the data, and to do so in a single spot for multiple data stores. There's nothing wrong with that, but in Android we tend to wait to do the migration until the first data access after the upgrade (see `onUpgrade()` of a `SQLiteOpenHelper`). This is cheap and easy, assuming that the migration work itself is cheap and easy. If the migration work will take some time -- enough that the user might wonder why it is taking so long to show their data -- then we need to consider proactive migration. That's not all that common.